# What is the rationale for using the genitive "такого" in "Такого, что многие даже не поверили бы!"?

Tags: падежи

> Я здесь многое повидал! **Такого**, что многие даже не поверили бы!
>
> == Here, I've seen a lot of things! Such things that most people wouldn't even believe!

Given that the word "такой" is used here as a replacement for the accusative "многое", the temptation is great to opt for the neuter accusative "**такое**" instead.

Comment: You can use both.

Comment: the sentences aren't consistent with each other, considering the content of the 1st sentence **такое** is the correct indicative pronoun

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the two sentences do not combine perfectly. The word **много** is *omitted* from the second sentence (много такого), which would be OK if it were present in the first sentence in the same form (to refer to), but it's мног**ое** instead of мног**о** there. And that gives a dissonance. Better correlated sentences:

> Я здесь многое повидал! **Много такого**, что многие даже не поверили бы!
>
> Я здесь **много** (чего) повидал! **Такого**, что многие даже не поверили бы!
>
> Я здесь **многое** повидал! И **такое**, (во) что многие даже не поверили бы!

Answer (score 3):

It’s normative to use accusative here (“я видел такое”), but in similar cases, especially in vernacular speech, genitive can also be heard (“я такого насмотрелся”). I think this stems from the extinct partitive case, further emphasizing the magnitude of things that were seen by suggesting those constituted only part of an even more magnificent whole.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a word formation mistake.

In Russian the accusative has two supporting questions, *“кого”* (like in genitive) for animate objects and *“что”* (like in nominative) for inanimate objects. However, nominative-like inanimate case looks inconvenient *in spoken language* because it interferes with an actual subject in its legal nominative. So it is often unintentionally replaced with a wrong form. Then it becomes a habit and goes into a written language.

So it can be treated as a some sort of style.